# Pass props to React component dependent on route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a root component which uses react-router:

```
<HashRouter>
  <aside>
    <Sidebar />
  </aside>
  <main>
    <Switch>
      {/* -- routes go here -- */}
    </Switch>
  </main>
</HashRouter>
```

I want my `Sidebar` component to have different content depending on which route we're on. So if I have two routes, `foo` and `bar`, when I go to `/foo` I want `Sidebar` to have different props than when I visit `/bar`. I've tried passing the `location` as a prop:

```
<Sidebar location={this.context.router.location.pathname} />
```

But I'm pretty sure that's not how it works... And sure enough it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

Comment: Yes that works. I'll mark it right if you want to put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to pass values from route to another component. This way you can do conditional rendering or implement any other logic related to the current route to your component.

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest
>   's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter
>   will re-render its component every time the route changes with the
>   same props as  render props: { match, location, history }.

**Example** *(from official documentation)*

```
// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
    )
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using React Router's `withRouter` to 'connect' the `<Sidebar />` component to the router.

With `withRouter` we create our `<Sidebar />` component as normal, then 'connect' it like this:

```
//Sidebar
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sidebar</h1> 
        <p>You are now at {this.props.location.pathname}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const SidebarWithRouter = withRouter(Sidebar);
```

In the end we have a new `<SidebarWithRouter />` component connected to the router so it has access to `match`, `location`, and `history`.

Unfortunately the code snippet won't work in Stackoverflow due to the `history` within the iframe, but here's the code, and a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/bYVaab?editors=1010).

```
let { BrowserRouter, Link, Route } = ReactRouterDOM;
let { Switch, withRouter } = ReactRouter;
let Router = BrowserRouter;

// App
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr />
          <aside>
            <SidebarWithRouter  />
          </aside>
          <Switch> 
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

//Home
const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>This is the Home Page.</p>
  </div>
);

//About
const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>This is about</p>
  </div>
);

//Sidebar
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sidebar</h1> 
        <p>You are now at {this.props.location.pathname}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const SidebarWithRouter = withRouter(Sidebar);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```